# How to access the file in another folder file_get_contents()

Tags: php, json, path, file-get-contents

This file is runing

```
my-site.com/includes/classes/build/cg.php
```

and it loads

```
my-site.com/data/data.json
```

with a such structure

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://my-site.com/data/data.json"), true);
```

I want to load it with relevant path, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After trying some combinations, realised this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ ."/../../../data/data.json"), true);
```

or

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("././././data/data.json"), true);
```